# C Program compiling despite incorrect number of arguments to function call

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I came across a C program as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum1(); //line A

int main()
{
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;

    int sum = sum1(a, b);  //line B
    printf("Sum: %d\n", sum);
}

int sum1(int a, int b, int c) //line C
{
    int sum = a + b + c;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, c);
    return sum;
}
```

I was surprised to see that the program compiles (gcc version 7.5.0) and gives the following as output:

```
2 3 3
Sum: 8
```

I can see 2 errors in this snippet:

1. The number of arguments in function declaration (line A) is not same as in function definition (line C)
2. Function call (line B) does not specify all 3 arguments needed in function definition (line C).

Compiling the program in C++ (using g++), does point out the 2 errors as I mentioned.

I am unable to understand how C is able to ignore such errors but am unable to find any documentation regarding the same. Any help in understanding this will be appreciated.

Comment: The compiler should have given you *warnings* if you have them turned on, but this is not an error. C is designed to be flexible about such things; functions with varyig bumbers and types of argument are quite legal and can be made without warnings if done properly.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker What's "an error" though? This is an obsolete language feature which is explicitly not recommended to be used (since year 1999). A decent compiler would give a warning along the lines of "the use of function declarators with empty parenthesis is deprecated" or something like that, but apparently none of the mainstream compilers do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int sum1();` forward declares a function for which the number of parameters and their types is unknown which is not in conflict with your definition of the function.

The below would however forward declare a function that does not take *any* arguments which *is* in conflict with your definition and will most probably result in a compilation error:

```
int sum1(void); //line A
```

The second problem is that you call `sum1` with 2 arguments when the function needs 3 (and you declared it as a function taking an unknown amount of arguments). The function will then pick an `int` worth of bytes from the stack (most likely) and use that. This corrupts the stack and makes your program have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: And what about error 2 ? I am not sure how the compiler can just assign a value for variable 'c'.

Comment: @Excalibur Sorry, I missed that part and added a note about that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error, though the compiler certainly will have issued *warnings* if you have them turned on. It is generally a good idea to turn on all compiler warnings and pay close attention to them.

Functions with varying number and types of arguments are legal and quite common in C, and can be made without warnings if declared properly.

Comment: `int sum1();` declares a function for which the number of parameters and their types is unknown, not a function that necessarily has a varying number or varying types of arguments.

Comment: Yes, but defining the function with three arguments and calling it with two should produce warnings--and maybe errors in newer standards. In old school C that's still not an error.